# Sequelize only update some column when i set all column in query

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

i'm tring to update a record in database (Postgres} using sequelize and express.
But when my code was executed, it only update 2 column, in fact that i've passed all the value for all column.
Try to debug but still have no clue, thanks in advance.

```
export const updateUserById = async (user) => {
  try {
    const result = await User.update(
      {
        // hard coding for testing purpose
        user_id: 144,
        user_role_id: 2,
        first_name: "Kanna",
        last_name: "Do",
        email: "kanna.do@email.com",
        is_active: true
      },
      {
        where: {
          user_id: user.user_id
        }
      }
    )
    return result
  } catch (error) {
    const message = { error: error };
    return message;
  }

}
```

here is the terminal log:

```
 Executing (default): UPDATE "demo"."user" SET "user_role_id"=$1,"email"=$2 WHERE "user_id" = $3
```

my route:

```
router.put('/user/:userId', userController.updateUserById);
```

Comment: Make sure all other column should be in schema, and why you need to update user_id again ?

Comment: yeah, i forgot to delete that field, was doing some testing so i pass all the field to check, i found out the error anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause, my column in schema using camelcase, I'm silly.